# PHP Access a variable inside a function of an object in an object of this object

Tags: php, function, oop, object

I have the following problem:

I have an object of the class 'Server'. This object has the variable $ip and an array $services[]. In the array is an object of the class Service. Is there a way to acces the variable $ip inside a function of the Service object?

```
class Server
{
    private ip;
    private services = [new Service()];
}

class Service
{
    function checkServiceStatus()
    {
        connectToServer($IP);
        // I need the IP of the Server it belongs to, in order to
        // connect to the server and check its status
    }
}

$WindowsServer = new Server();
```

This is a simple code example for my problem. It would be nice if I could access the $IP variable of the Server object the Service object belongs to.

Comment: It depends how you will use the value of `$ip` (which is why a code example with your question is useful). If you will invoke a method of the instance of `Service` held in the array from within another method of `Server`, you can pass `$this->ip` as an argument to that method call. If you will keep the value of `$ip` as an attribute of the `Service` instance, then pass it as an argument to the constructor when it is called before stored in the array (e.g. `$services[] = new Service($this->ip)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just converting @jeyoung comment to code:

```
class Server
{
    private $ip;
    private $services = [];

    function __construct($ip) {
      $this->ip = $ip;
      $this->services[] = new Service($this->ip);
    }
}

class Service
{
    function __construct($ip) {
      $this->ip = $ip;
    }

    function checkServiceStatus()
    {
        connectToServer($this->ip);
        // I need the IP of the Server it belongs to, in order to
        // connect to the server and check its status
    }
}

$WindowsServer = new Server('127.0.0.1'); // for example
```

Comment: You are missing the constructor in `Server` and you don't provide the `$ip` to `new Service()`.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote it too quickly... :-(

Comment: Thanks for the answers :), I also had this solution on my mind, but I thought that there maybe would be a way to read it everytime directly from the server object. So that if the server ip changes, the service also uses the right ip.